# 32-bit icon with ExtractAssociatedIcon

Tags: vb.net, icons

When I save the Extracted icon I have only 8-bit channel icon. How can I get 32-bit icon?
Here is the code I use:

```
Public Sub LoadIcon()
   Dim path = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop + "\icon\"
   Dim filePath As String = "С:/Windows/explorer.exe"
   Dim TheIcon As Icon = IconFromFilePath(filePath)
   If TheIcon IsNot Nothing Then
      Using stream As New System.IO.FileStream(path + "programicon.ico",       IO.FileMode.CreateNew)
         TheIcon.Save(stream)
      End Using
   End If
   PictureBox1.Load(path + "programicon.ico")
End Sub

Public Function IconFromFilePath(ByVal filePath As String) As Icon
    Dim result As Icon = Nothing
    Try
        result = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath)
    Catch
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

It's returning this icon:

[image]

Comment: The Icon class was made to work on ancient operating systems that were supported by .NET, like Win98 and Win2000.  Type "shgetfileinfo SHGFI_LARGEICON" in the search box.

Comment: It works, but I still get the 8-bit icon. I found about shgetfileinfo SHGFI_LARGEICON here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find the largest icon using shgetfileinfo, maybe if you use `SHIL_LAST` or `SHIL_JUMBO` (starting with Windows Vista) you will find 32-bit color icon. More information about `SHIL_LAST` and `SHIL_JUMBO` you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).